# View.OnClickListener usage as parameter in Android

Tags: java, android

Interface names do not end with "()".

And from Android documentation View.OnClickListener is defined as interface.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Having said that, when we pass "View.OnClickListener" to a listener as a parameter why do we have to do end it "()" as shown below.

```
.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: its a annonymous inner class.

Comment: Yes figured it may be the case..but still could not understand why the () was used on an interface...anyways tx

Answer (score 4):

It's syntax of [Anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which **enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time.**

```
.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

//all methods in the interface  implemented here

});
```

That `setOnClickListener`  taking an object of type implemented by `OnClickListener`,Instead  of creating an object with that interface,directly implementing the methods there.

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket of the method and the semicolon.

Comment: @DanielLerps  Thanks,fixed that. I though that is quite obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Its a annonymous inner class

Say you have a button

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {

   } 

 });
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

You can also do as

```
  button.setOnClickListener(myclicklistener);

  OnClickListener myclickListener = new OnClickListener() // now you know why you ()
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {

     } 
  };
```

Quoting from the java docs

The anonymous class expression consists of the following:

- The new operator
- The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend.
- Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a 
  normal class instance creation expression. Note: **When you implement

  an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of

  parentheses, as in this example.**
- A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the 
  body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

Answer (score 1):

On click listener is an interface.

Syntax

```
variable.setOnClicklistener(new View.OnClickListener()
{})
```

This is the way we can use onClicklistener.

Answer (score 1):

Because we're initiating anonymous class here. Thus an interface becomes an object which is passed as a parameter.

You coul do this way:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
    }
};
someView.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are creating an Object which implements that particular interface. It is a constructor call on an anonymous inner class which you define via the method in the block that follows.

```
something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View invoker)
   {
       // this is a method specified by the interface. The new Object will have this method implementation
   }
});
```

Comment: is `invoker` is  the same as `something` (same reference but upcasted)?